# Analytics API: PHP quickstart for service accounts

Tags: php, google-analytics

I am following below article to get analytics data on my website,

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php#3_setup_the_sample

but it's getting stuck at line no 35 -

```
$accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();
```

It's not getting `listManagementAccounts()` method.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Need to add user to analytics account.